# How to modified input value based on dropdown list value change angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have several input fields that their values need to be changed based on a dropdown list value change. For example if dropdown value = default, input a value = '', input b value = 'b'; if dropdown value = 'a', input a value = 'a', input b value =''. How can I archive that? I am using template form. Thank you for your help.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Initially, you will have to detect the change in the selected drop-down, that can be done by,

**HTML**

```
<select  (change)="select($event)" >
    <option value="a"> A </option>
    <option value="b"> B </option>
</select>
```

**TS**

```
select(event){
if(event.target.value === 'a' ){
this.texta= '';
this.textb = 'b';
} else {
this.texta= 'a';
this.textb = '';
}
}
```

then those value can be assigned to input fields.

Comment: hi @Abhishek, is texta the name of the input field or ngModel binding name? and what is this for? I am new here, so bear with me.

Comment: if you want to bind it with ngmodel you can just assign it. it was just for understanding. the appropriate way would be binding with ngmodel.